# Encrypt / Decrypt data with AES between c# and PHP - decrypted data starts with 255,254

Tags: c#, php, encryption, cryptography

I have to request data from an external existing webservice written in C#.
This webservice requires some of the data to be encrypted (The connection uses an SSL connection, some of the data is aes encrypted)

On the php site openssl is used for decrypting.

The following settings are used on the c# site 
(This are the default values for the AesCryptoServiceProvider):

- Algorithm: AES
- Padding: PKCS7
- Mode: CBC
- Keysize: 256

The padding for PKCS7 works as following:
01      If 1 byte is missing
02 02   If 2 bytes are missing
and so on

so this values are not added by the padding.

What am I doing wrong?

I've checked this with c#, php and ruby - the decrypted data starts with 255, 254

To reproduce use the following parameters:

data:1234567890123456
key: First1
salt(iv):Data

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace crypto_test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                bool running = true;
                while (running)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter data:");
                    var data = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter key:");
                    var key = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter iv:");
                    var iv = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter d for decode");
                    var decode = (Console.ReadLine() == "d");

                    string encoded=Crypt(data, key, iv, decode);
                    Console.WriteLine(encoded);
                    if (!decode)
                    {
                        encoded=  Crypt(encoded, key, iv, true);
                        Console.WriteLine(encoded);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("quit to exit");
                    running = !(Console.ReadLine() == "quit");
                }

        }

        public static string Crypt(string value, string password, string salt, bool decrypt)
        {
            DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));
            SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
            byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);

            Console.WriteLine("rbKey: size:{0} key:{1}", (algorithm.KeySize >> 3), GetHex(rgbKey));
            Console.WriteLine("rgbIV: size:{0} key:{1}", (algorithm.BlockSize >> 3), GetHex(rgbIV));

            ICryptoTransform transform = decrypt ? algorithm.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV) : algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);
            Console.WriteLine("Mode {0}", algorithm.Mode);
            Console.WriteLine("PAdding {0}", algorithm.Padding);

            using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (decrypt)
                        {
                            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
                            stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                            {
                                writer.Write(value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    }
                }

                byte[] buff = buffer.ToArray();
                if (decrypt)
                {
                    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buff) + "\r\n" + GetHex(buff);
                }
                else
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(buff);
            }
        }

        public static string GetHex(byte[] data)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
                sb.Append(data[i].ToString("X2"));
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have not found an equivalent to Rfc2898DeriveBytes until now,
so I copied the key and iv

php

```
<?php

$salt='Data';
$pass='First1';
$data='1234567890123456';

$encrypted_base64='VKNd9Pi+cttaM6ne8pzAuFbH1U0gJiJ2Wlbbr1rU5z8vbIfAS6nb0/5py4p54aK7';
$encrypted=base64_decode($encrypted_base64);
$key = pack('H*', "30EE7F95F0EF4835F048A481424F2F52EE21B7CEB97F8CC437E5949DB53797D9");
$iv = pack('H*', "B29F5ECF7057065758102385509F0637");
$cipher='AES-256-CBC';
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted,$cipher, $key,true,$iv);
for($i =0; $i<strlen($decrypted);++$i)
{
    echo "char:" . ord($decrypted[$i])."<br/>";
}
echo $decrypted
?>
```

ruby:

```
require ('openssl')
require ('base64')

while true


enc_data='VKNd9Pi+cttaM6ne8pzAuFbH1U0gJiJ2Wlbbr1rU5z8vbIfAS6nb0/5py4p54aK7'

data = Base64.decode64(enc_data)

key_hex='30EE7F95F0EF4835F048A481424F2F52EE21B7CEB97F8CC437E5949DB53797D9'
iv_hex='B29F5ECF7057065758102385509F0637'


key = [key_hex].pack('H*')
iv = [iv_hex].pack('H*')

decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(256, :CBC)
decipher.decrypt
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv
plain = decipher.update(data) + decipher.final

puts plain
puts plain.bytes

end
```

Comment: the problem is that if i decode the data again, it starts with 255, 254 and I don't know why. I added the code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, your decryption seems to work OK.

What you are seeing in the decrypted ciphertext is the byte order mark for UTF-16 LE, which is (incorrectly) indicated by Microsoft as `Encoding.Unicode`. You need to do either one off two things:

1. decode the text with a decoder that groks UTF-16 LE including byte order mark;
2. encode using much more reasonable [UTF-8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx) encoding (in the C# code).

Personally I would put a strong preference on (2).